# How to fetch data from multiple table according to id by using query builder in laravel

Tags: laravel

How to fetch data from multiple table according to id by using query builder in Laravel?

example:

I have three tables such as student,parent and teacher.Now I want to fetch data from this three tables(student,parent and teacher) according to id for editing.So how can I do that?
see bellow codes please

```php
 public function edit($id) 
{
 $values=DB::table("student")->find($id); 
 $values=DB::table("parent")->find($id);
 $values=DB::table("teacher")->find($id);
 return view("info", compact("values"));
}
```

Comment: need more information, DB schema, and what you want to get.

Comment: You can find a lot of information on the laravel homepage: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries So please ask a more specific question

Comment: Using join  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: namelivia,How can i join three table in this bellow code          public function edit($id){   $values=DB::table("student")->find($id);                   return view("info",compact("values"))                                 }

Comment: AgeValed,  Example:I have three tables such as student,parent and teacher.Now i want to fetch data from this three tables(student,parent and teacher) according to id and then update this data.So how can i do that? see this bellow code please. public function edit($id) { $values=DB::table("student")->find($id); $values=DB::table("parent")->find($id); $values=DB::table("teacher")->find($id); return view("info", compact("values")); }

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to fetch data according to id that you have. Of course that other tables need to have foreign keys of that table>

Here is laravel documentation for joins:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins

and here is example code from docs:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Source Edin.                                                                                                   Example:I have three tables such as student,parent and teacher.Now i want to fetch data from this three tables(student,parent and teacher) according to id and then update this data.So how can i do that? see this bellow code please.                            public function edit($id) 
{
 $values=DB::table("student")->find($id); 
 $values=DB::table("parent")->find($id);
 $values=DB::table("teacher")->find($id);
 return view("info", compact("values"));
}

Comment: Hey man:

$allData = DB::table('student')
            ->join('parent', 'student.id', '=', 'parent.student_id')
            ->join('teacher', 'student.id', '=', 'teacher.student_id')
            ->select('student.*', 'parent.*', 'teacher.*')
            ->get();